# Difference in Setting paths of wxwidgets in c++static library & c++ application

Tags: c++, linker, wxwidgets, static-libraries

I am stuck with a major problem here , i have wxwidgets-2.8.12(Latest stable release) with Netbeans 7.1.1 i made a sample project for using wxwidgets ,at the time of creation of the c++ application (sample project) i included the wxwidgets path in the ways provided at this link

visit http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_using_Netbeans

However in my scenario i have a static library instead so i need to ask about how to associate `wx-config --libs`in c++ static library as there is no linker option instead there is Archiever.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A static library in only a collection of object files. You are not able to associate a static library with others.

Provide yourself a `yourproject-config` script for other if you what to redistribute your project for developers that calls `wx-config --libs` and append your library to the caller.

Only shared objects are able to associate with others.

Comment: "yourproject-config" i really don't get this my objective is to achieve what i achieved using the link cited above and to get rid of undefined refernces errors,just to add i build my wxwidgets libraries using SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=0 BUILD=release

Comment: I really don't get anything from the link, may be the scenario if different , one thing i forgot to tell that i have got a test file as well in the c++ static library project so what i did was ->properties->inker->libraries->`wx-config --libs` in the test file properties , dont know whether it is right or not

Comment: Ok another try. You should add the output of `wx-config --libs` in the settings. The wiki site surround the call with the \` sign which is the short form for the output of the call.

Comment: I run wx-config --libs in the cmd and got the following,i guess you are talking about this stuff , asyou wrote add these in settings i was not able to find it ,did you mean right clik ->properties->archiever->additional options or something else 
 -mthreads -LD:\wxWidgets2812\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_dll -lwxmsw28_html -lwxmsw28_adv -lwxmsw28_core -lwxbase28_xml -lwxbase28_net -lwxbase28 -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng -lwxzlib -lwxregex -lwxexpat -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwxregex -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lwsock32

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans but you have to add exactly this output to your linker options.

Comment: I added `wx-config --libs` (as this would serve the same purpose of adding the libraries individually)in the test file properties->linker options ,can you suggest what i might face either as error or something like that.

Comment: `wx-config` is not found in your `PATH` environment?

Comment: 13:40:57: Error: Can't create thread (error 8: not enough storage is available to process this command.)
13:40:57: Error: Can not resume thread 0 (error 6: the handle is invalid.)
13:40:57: Error: Can not wait for thread termination (error 6: the handle is invalid.)
13:40:57: Error: Couldn't terminate thread (error 6: the handle is invalid.)

Comment: This is vacuous. In order to give you the right answer you have to be more detailed. Which applications are started with witch parameters?